# Collision realisation with SAT (canvas, javascript)

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision

So, I have this [simple 2d train sim](https://c9.io/sergeypetushkov/trains/workspace/trains.html), and I already made a pretty nice SAT realisation, that works without errors (at least I have not stumbled upon any):

```
function calcCollision(self){
    var dist = self.distanceCheck();
    var possible = [], collision = [];
    var myBox, otherBox, myMin, myMax, otherMin, otherMax, myBoxRecalc = [], otherBoxRecalc = [];

    for (var i=0;i<trainCount;i++){
        if (dist[i]!="SELF"&&dist[i]<=(dTrain+10)){
            possible.push(i);
        }
    }

    if (possible.length!==0){

        myBox = self.box();

        self.hit = false;

        for (i=0;i<possible.length;i++){
            otherBox = window["train_"+possible[i]].box();

            //для self координат

            for (var j=0;j<4;j++){
                myBoxRecalc[j] = XYtoBoxCoordinates(self,myBox[j][0],myBox[j][1]);
                otherBoxRecalc[j] = XYtoBoxCoordinates(self,otherBox[j][0],otherBox[j][1]);
            }

            //для self координат, проекция на X

            myMin = myBoxRecalc[0][0];
            myMax = myBoxRecalc[0][0];

            otherMin = otherBoxRecalc[0][0];
            otherMax = otherBoxRecalc[0][0];

            for (j=0;j<4;j++){
                if (myBoxRecalc[j][0]<myMin) myMin=myBoxRecalc[j][0];
                if (myBoxRecalc[j][0]>myMax) myMax=myBoxRecalc[j][0];

                if (otherBoxRecalc[j][0]<otherMin) otherMin=otherBoxRecalc[j][0];
                if (otherBoxRecalc[j][0]>otherMax) otherMax=otherBoxRecalc[j][0];
            }

            //console.log(myMin + " " + myMax + " " + otherMin + " " + otherMax);

            if (otherMax<myMin||otherMin>myMax) break;

            //для self координат, проекция на Y

            myMin = myBoxRecalc[0][1];
            myMax = myBoxRecalc[0][1];

            otherMin = otherBoxRecalc[0][1];
            otherMax = otherBoxRecalc[0][1];

            for (j=0;j<4;j++){
                if (myBoxRecalc[j][1]<myMin) myMin=myBoxRecalc[j][1];
                if (myBoxRecalc[j][1]>myMax) myMax=myBoxRecalc[j][1];

                if (otherBoxRecalc[j][1]<otherMin) otherMin=otherBoxRecalc[j][1];
                if (otherBoxRecalc[j][1]>otherMax) otherMax=otherBoxRecalc[j][1];
            }

            //console.log(myMin + " " + myMax + " " + otherMin + " " + otherMax);

            if (otherMax<myMin||otherMin>myMax) break;

            //для other координат

            for (j=0;j<4;j++){
                myBoxRecalc[j] = XYtoBoxCoordinates(window["train_"+possible[i]],myBox[j][0],myBox[j][1]);
                otherBoxRecalc[j] = XYtoBoxCoordinates(window["train_"+possible[i]],otherBox[j][0],otherBox[j][1]);
            }

            //для other координат, проекция на X

            myMin = myBoxRecalc[0][0];
            myMax = myBoxRecalc[0][0];

            otherMin = otherBoxRecalc[0][0];
            otherMax = otherBoxRecalc[0][0];

            for (j=0;j<4;j++){
                if (myBoxRecalc[j][0]<myMin) myMin=myBoxRecalc[j][0];
                if (myBoxRecalc[j][0]>myMax) myMax=myBoxRecalc[j][0];

                if (otherBoxRecalc[j][0]<otherMin) otherMin=otherBoxRecalc[j][0];
                if (otherBoxRecalc[j][0]>otherMax) otherMax=otherBoxRecalc[j][0];
            }

            //console.log(myMin + " " + myMax + " " + otherMin + " " + otherMax);

            if (otherMax<myMin||otherMin>myMax) break;

            //для other координат, проекция на Y

            myMin = myBoxRecalc[0][1];
            myMax = myBoxRecalc[0][1];

            otherMin = otherBoxRecalc[0][1];
            otherMax = otherBoxRecalc[0][1];

            for (j=0;j<4;j++){
                if (myBoxRecalc[j][1]<myMin) myMin=myBoxRecalc[j][1];
                if (myBoxRecalc[j][1]>myMax) myMax=myBoxRecalc[j][1];

                if (otherBoxRecalc[j][1]<otherMin) otherMin=otherBoxRecalc[j][1];
                if (otherBoxRecalc[j][1]>otherMax) otherMax=otherBoxRecalc[j][1];
            }

            //console.log(myMin + " " + myMax + " " + otherMin + " " + otherMax);

            if (otherMax<myMin||otherMin>myMax) break;

            collision.push(possible[i]);

        }
    } else return false;

    if (collision.length!==0){
        self.hit = true;
        return collision;
    } else return false;
}
```

It detects possible collision objects for `self` and returns their ID's if there is a collision. As I already said, it works just fine. The problem appears after that, when i'm trying to create a reaction on the collision. I've been struggling over the algorithm for almost a week, and that's the best solution that I came up with:

```
function moveCollided(){

    for (var i = 0; i < trainCount; i++) {
        var banged = calcCollision(window["train_"+i]);
        //console.log(banged);
        if (window["train_"+i].hit){
            window["train_"+i].speed -= (window["train_"+i].speed/3);
            for (var j = 0; j < banged.length; j++) {
                window["train_"+banged[j]].speed += calcSpeedIncrement(window["train_"+i],window["train_"+banged[j]]);
            }
        }
    }

    setTimeout(moveCollided, 15);
}
```

This function decreases the speed of the train, and adds some speed (`calcSpeedIncrement(self,other)`) to the train it crashed into. I'm getting a nice collision effect in the straight tracks, but if you keep pushing forward one train slides over the other. And another problem with the same "sliding over" is the collision when one of the trains is standing on the turn.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve these problems?

Answer (score -1):

I would simple not try to re-invent the wheel and go for an existing solution. Have you looked at the very popular 2D-physics engine [Box2D](http://www.box2d.org)? [Here is a nice implementation of it](http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/) in JavaScript.

Comment: Eric, I started writing this code to study JavaScript. This is my first project and the goal here is to write the "simple" engine from scratch without using third-party solutions. Thanks for the advice, I've heard of Box2D, and some other physical engines for JavaScript, but this is not what I need :)

Comment: While it's true that there are often existing solutions that can save time and effort, telling someone not to "reinvent the wheel" doesn't necessarily help them solve their problem. How will they learn to code better if all you say is "go get something that is already working"? Your answer doesn't help anybody.